# Make words clickable in Richtext Editor Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor, nicedit

Hiiii Everyone,

I have a Rich text Editor(using nicEditor).I want to make each words in richtextEditor clickable so that onclick of word will change background of particular word and again click removes bg which works like toggle.So that I triedin 1st step to make the words clickable I wanna wrap each words with span tag.

```
var myInstance1 = new nicEditor({
    iconsPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'
  }).panelInstance('differ_paragraph'); 
myInstance1.addEvent('blur', function() { 
var text1 = this.instanceById('differ_paragraph').getContent(); 
var nicInstance1 = nicEditors.findEditor('differ_paragraph');
 var words =  nicInstance1.getContent().split(" ");
nicEditors.findEditor("differ_paragraph").setContent(' ');
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    nicEditors.findEditor("differ_paragraph").setContent($("<span>").text(v));
});

});
```

I tried like above but Its return object.What is the issue? Please anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error in firebug console ?

Comment: Any solution on this ?

Comment: No. @MittulAtTechnoBrave .

Comment: Ohk. You can put this question on Bounty. You will get answers and get your solution quickly.

Comment: No. I had tried already.

Comment: :) hahaha......

Comment: can you give me plugin link of richtext editor which you used.

Comment: http://nicedit.com/demos.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139816/discussion-between-mittul-at-technobrave-and-kavya-shree).